# Ruby on Rails(3.2) Routing Error when route exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

Having an issue with my routes that is confusing me. Basically I have a user Has_many workers and a worker belongs_to a user active record setup. So I wanted to do nested routes. Below is my routes file

```
resources :users do
 resources :workers
end 
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
root to: 'info_pages#home'
match '/contact', to: 'info_pages#contact'
match '/about', to: 'info_pages#about'
match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete 
match '/pools', to: 'pools#new'
match '/settings', to: 'info_pages#settings'
```

I run rake routes and I see all the nested routes

I went in to my worker controller and have this code

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end

 def show
 end

 def update
 end

 def create
 end

end
```

Now when I try to load the page with this link

```
<li><%= link_to "Workers", new_user_worker_path %></li>
```

The load fails saying "No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"workers"}"

Im not sure why its failing on this route when I clearly have it defined in the routes file and Maybe my controller isn't setup correctly for the nested routes. 
Thank you!

Comment: You clearly do *not* have such a route defined. Your `new_user_work_path` requires a user for whom to create a worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `user` variable

```
<li><%= link_to "Workers", new_user_worker_path(@user) %></li>
```

or for devise probably you'll want

```
<li><%= link_to "Workers", new_user_worker_path(current_user) %></li>
```

Comment: Thank you rmagnum2002 you solved my problem! Question If I wanted to user the user I would have to add to the workers controller @user = User.find(params[:id])? Thank you again

Comment: sure, you have to load the user but how you do it it dependes on how your app works. Needs more details about what you do at this point and for whom.. for ex: you, as a currently logged_in user want to ad a worker, or you want to add a worker for user that's in db. These cases have a different aproach.

Comment: In first case you load the user from a method that will save your user into session and can be used in views and controllers, and the second case is where you are on the page of some user and want to add a worker for him having an url like `../users/1/workers/new` when the form for worker is loaded you can get the user from params[:id]

Comment: I am running into a problem with my Form_for(@worker) getting a no method errors even tho controller has def new @worker = Worker.new I think I missing something

Comment: having worker as a subresource of user `form_for @worker` won't work, try with `<%= form_for @user, @worker do |f| %>`

Comment: and also you'll need to find the @user here, load it from params or it's the current user.. can't say as I don't see your app code

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do us a favor and run "rake routes" to see the output?  That should tell you what routes your system is actually considering as defined.